# How do I connect Biostar V1.8 Suprema to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm installing Biostar Suprema apps V1.8. Currently the default DB is using MSSQL.
How can I change the DB from MSSQL to MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the steps:

1. Install MySQL DB and Run MySQL DB service.
2. Install *mysql-connector-odbc-5.1.10-win32.msi* <-- must use this version of odbc
3. Stop the Biostar Server Service at services.msc
4. Stop MSSQL Service
5. Next, Go to folder --> C:\Program Files\BioStar\server\
   and run file DBSetup.exe
6. The system will ask "Do you want to install MSSQL?" Choose "No"
7. Then a window will pop-up. Choose Database MySQL and Insert Host, Port, ID and Password.
8. Startup the Biostar Server Service.
9. Open Client Login and try to Login.

Hopefully this answer will be beneficial to everyone.

p/s: **The most important is the odbc version** (refer above step 2)

Comment: This did the trick for me, indeed the correct version of the MySQL ODBC drivers seems to be crucial. Archived versions can be found here: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-odbc/

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert the BioStar installation CD into a compatible media drive.
2. Locate the installation directory and run BioStar 1.8 Setup.
3. Follow the on-screen prompts to begin the installation.
4. During the installation, you will be asked to select the language of your preference.
5. Select a language, then click Next to proceed.
6. Follow the instructions on the screen to finish the installation.
7. During the installation, you will be required to accept the OpenSSL license agreement
   and select a destination folder for the OpenSSL program files.
8. You will also be asked whether or not you wish to install the MS SQL Server Express
   edition. If you will use a pre-installed version of MS SQL Server, MySQL or Oracle, you
   may click No when this message appears. If you decide to use the express edition in this step, you can skip to step 10. The database setup process will be automated when you install the express edition.
9. When the Create Database [BioStar] dialog box appears, select a database type (MS
   SQL Server, MySQL or Oracle). The database server address and port numbers will be
   automatically populated, but you should verify that they are correct.

**Configure the MySQL Database**

BioStar cannot use the MySQL database if the maximum packet size is less than 16MB. To configure the maximum packet size n MySQL server, locate and open a configuration file for the MySQL server (`“my.ini”` for a Windows system or `“my.cnf”` for a Linux system).

Under `[mysqld]`, add or edit the packet size to 16M or bigger (for example: `max_allowed_packet=16M`). After you have changed and saved the file, restart the BioStar Server for the changes to take effect.

[Complete Manual PDF](https://www.supremainc.com/sites/default/files/biostar_ug_v1.8_en.pdf)